# Xcode load ViewController without releasing the old one

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, uitabbarcontroller, gallery, retain

I have a `UITabViewController`, where I have **5 viewcontrollers**. And in one off them I have a view with thumbnails, and i want to go to fullscreen, when i tap on one of the photos. But to do that fullscreen I've to do a new `ViewController`, and when I come back from that view controller, I've lost all the info that I had on the uitab views :(

Can you please help me with that?

Comment: Device or simulator?  If it's the device, you may be having your view unloaded because of a memory warning.

Comment: show us some code when you create your tabbar , create that new viewcontroller and come back from it.. and we might be able to help.. :)

Comment: I've created a UItabbarcontroller, and after that, I created 5 viewcontrollers for that 5 tabs, all in the storyboard. Now i created a new viewcontroller, but i don't want it to appear like a tab. Is there anyway to associate it to the tabbarcontroller, but don't show his tab? In that way, the info will never be lost (my data comes from a JSON).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if u are using arc it will no longer available,so u should create property for your view then its reference wont go away.then u can go like this

```
    if(EventRegisterView==nil)
    EventRegisterView = [[EventRegisterViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"EventRegisterViewController" bundle:nil];
```

Comment: Sorry but i'm a little noob yet. I'm using ARC indeed. So I've to put this code where? On the viewdidunload og my thumbanails view?